# customelement not visible when clicking on index.html

Tags: typescript, invisible

I have made a customelement with typescript; compiles ok to js and when i put the files in StackBlitz (online), then the customelement works fine, but when i open index.html local the customelement is not visible. Is it possible to test the customelement local with a browser or is it necessary to load the html file and javascript file via http?